# What happens if a user (Mike) is being funny (not disrespectful), posting useless comments etc.?

Tags: discussion

As mentioned in the title, if a user is being funny e.g. he is writing sarcastic comments, asking funny questions, or answers that may not answer the question but are just intended to be funny, what can the community do for such a user and what should the community do? My specific site of interest here is Stack Overflow.

Comment: [We hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), if you're looking for a humour outlet please find somewhere else

Comment: Is this about me? I think this is about me.  This is about me, isn't it. This is about me.

Comment: @Will Yes, this is about me :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non constructive (funny or sarcastic) questions can be closed as off topic. You can flag such a question with **Flag -> Should be closed -> Off Topic** and then select the option that fits best.

Non constructive comments can be deleted when you flag them as non constructive. To do that you can click "**flag**" on the comment and select "**Non constructive**".

Non constructive Answers (Answers that clearly don't even attempt to answer the question) can be flagged as "Not An Answer" (NAA). To do that click on the "**flag**" link underneath the answer and choose "**Not an Answer**".

Now, if the answer is sarcastic but still answers the question, you should not flag it as not an answer. Instead just downvote and move on.

In any case for unconstructive questions and answers, downvoting is appropiate.

Comment: thanks :) . Marking it as answer. So, now I can be funny if on some days I feel like so ;) . Actually just today, on a post (which was not mine), I started replying to comments like I was the OP. the OP was slow to respond. And the fun part was that people got confused and started talking to me like I was the OP ;) :p .

Comment: @Mike not sure how you concluded from this answer that that kind of behaviour is OK; it's not, particularly if you're confusing people.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hmm, you're right :( Didn't want to confuse though. Just replied to a comment as per my understanding of the question. Regarding how I concluded, I just wanted to know people cannot close off a user like they can close off or downvote a question :p

Comment: @Mike ...but they *can*; comments can be flagged for deletion, and if you attract a lot of valid flags you can expect a moderator to give you a [timeout](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Comment: @jonrsharpe great thanks for the links. I will keep these things in mind :)